# Power app component property of type color defaults to black

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

In a power app canvas app,  I created a component (MyComponent) and added custom property (MyColor) that is of type Color.  If I add a child component and set its fill value to the property (MyComponent.MyColor) then the child component will assume a value of black RGBA(0,0,0,1) at design-time and runtime because I haven't explicitly set the value of the property yet.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to put a default on the property value?  I'd rather the default be something transparent rather than a fully opaque black.
2. Is it possible to test if the property value has been set?  So far I can only test to see if it is black, but it may have been explicitly set to black or not have been set at all, so simply comparing to RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1) doesn't work in all cases.

   If(MyComponent.MyColor = RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1), "Color may not have been specified", "Color was specified")

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can set a default property value. In your component, select the Property under Custom Properties, then in the formula bar, change/set it to what you like.  You will see that by default it would have been set to `RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1)`

   [image]
2. Since the property is of type Color, it will always have a value set (as per 1. above).